# Using <strong> and <em> as block elements?

Tags: html, css

I have some HTML that looks like this:

```
<div class="position-container">
  <div class="top-position">1</div>
  <div class="current-position">2</div>
</div>
```

I won't bother adding the style here, but basically the 1 and 2 are each block elements with specific background colors. Some dude I work for doesn't like me using so many divs, so he wants me to change the first div in "position-container" to `<strong>` and the second to `<em>` and then change their display to block.

I was under the impression that those elements should be used within a block of text to indicate emphasis within a given context. I also thought they were semantically to be used in an inline manner. Am I off the mark? Should I really just be arbitrarily throwing around `<strong>` and `<em>` tags once my `<div>` count gets a bit high?

Comment: What's the point of make it with tag strong if you still need a block? Sounds like more inefficient css

Comment: Yeah, the dude you work with is wrong. you shouldn't use strong and em unless you're using them on inline text that you want to bring emphasis to.

Comment: If it doesn't validate, it shouldn't be done at all.

Comment: Your understanding of `em` and `strong` as phrase elements is correct.  Your colleague is wrong. You could use more semantic elements though, like `nav` or `section` according to what you need to do.

Comment: Using a `div` for a block level element is WAY more semantic than turning inline elements like `em` or `strong` into block elements.  The dude you work with is wrong and you should tell him to read more about semantics because there are much worse things in that regard than a lil old div soup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem shouldn't be that you have too many HTML elements that are divs, but the problem arises if you have too many HTML elements tout court.

"Some dude" in your story is, then, wrong in my opinion. In some cases - and possibly for some SEO benefits - some HTML elements are preferred over others, but you can't just look at a HTML page and say "Well, I see so many div tags, why not change this to that and that to this and it looks prettier!"

The thing I would look at is: how can I make my HTML structure more semantically logical. This would probably involve all te new [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) elements. The use of `section`, `article`, `aside`, `nav` and `role` attributes make a page much more intuitive and logical. Basically, with HTML5 you can show a person that knows nothing of webcoding the code of your HTML5 page and by simply looking at the tags you used, he can easily derive what is important and what not. That's the beauty of HTML5.

So, before randomly starting to change some div tags to strong tags, consider HTML5. And you might also want to ask WHY "some dude" wants you to change it. Maybe he does have a legitmate reason, you never know!

Answer (score 1):

Strong and Em are inline tags that should be used to either bold or add italics to words themselves. That's basically it. They shouldn't be block elements. Not really their purpose.

The guy saying you have too many divs, and recommending the used of either strong or em as block elements to alleviate this issue is incredibly off base in their approach.

I would recommend, to at least offer up something different, use HTML5 element tags such as article, section, header, footer, etc. to make the code a little more readable. Assuming that's what you're looking for.

If you need to support older browsers that don't recognize newer tags. Take a look at something like Modernizr.js.

Comment: Careful how you phrase that—strong should be used FOR STRONG EMPHASIS, and em for EMPHASIS. Bolding and italics are just the most standard way to do that. I see nothing wrong with an emphasized bit of text suddenly being a block element, in bright orange, filling the page, if that's the designed intent.